# How show all tooltips split in graph with many series

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

I have the following graph: [Highcharts Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/silviokucharski/go1eem4h/)

When the graph is small (because the screen is small, less than 1024x768), some tooltips are hidden by default. I would like show all tooltips in each column regardless of the size of the chart.
The example shows 5 tooltips, but 7 tooltips should be shown.
Is there any way to change this behavior?

```
tooltip: {
  valueSuffix: '°C',
  split: true,
  enabled: true,
  padding: 2,
  useHTML: true,
  pointFormatter: function () {                    
    return '<span style="color:'+this.series.color+'">'+this.series.name+'</span>: '+this.y
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To save space, use shared instead of split tooltips.  I also made the tooltip svg instead of html.  The scaling seems to work better.

```
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '°C',
    split: false,
    shared: true,
    enabled: true,
    padding: 2,
    useHTML: false,
    pointFormatter: function() {
      return '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + '</span>: ' + this.y + '<br/>'
    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/blaird/go1eem4h/1/
      },

Comment: I'm going to make your suggestion as a temporary solution and I'm still trying because I like split more than shared

Comment: How do you want it displayed when the chart is small?  Scale the text down?

Comment: I post a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution: according to the size of the graph I updated the padding and font size of tooltip. In my case, when the graphic is greater than 205px, the original configuration (padding 2 and font 11.5) is used. When between 205 and 170px is updated to padding 0 and font 9.5, and less than 170px use tooltip shared

```
$("#container").resize(function () {
  if ($(this).height() < 205 && $(this).height() >= 170) {
    chart.update({
      tooltip: {
        shared: false,
        split: true,
        padding: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: '9.5px'
        },
      }
    });
  } else if ($(this).height() < 170) {
    chart.update({
      tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        split: false,
        padding: 2,
        style: {
          fontSize: '11.5px'
        },
      }
    });
  } else {
    chart.update({
      tooltip: {
        shared: false,
        split: true,
        padding: 2,
        style: {
          fontSize: '11.5px'
        },
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: EDIT: In new versions (5.0.0+) of highcharts, I can do chart.update